# OpenCV (gamma) in addWeighted function

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

In OpenCV (c++) addWeighted function

```
void addWeighted(InputArray src1, double alpha, InputArray src2, double beta, double gamma, OutputArray dst, int dtype=-1)
```

gamma is the scalar added to each sum.

How do we make it 'wrap around' for large values of gamma?

When I give gamma as 255, I just get a white screen

Comment: What would be your expectation for gamma == 255 ?

Comment: I was hoping it would 'wrap around' and give me the same image

Comment: And what if the value is 230 ?

Comment: Then it should be slightly darker as 230 ~ -25

Comment: I don't think this is how addition works. What is your ultimate goal with this? Maybe there is different viable approach?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I'm guessing that you're receiving `gamma` dynamically in your code, and you're not hard-coding it to a fixed value.

In that case, I would advise you to perform an intermediate arithmetic operation on `gamma` before supplying it to `addWeighted()`

A simple example would would be:

```
int wrap_around_thresh=150;//let's suppose
int gamma=getGammaValue(params)//if you're getting it dynamically

if(gamma < wrap_around_thresh){
     //doNothing
}else{
     gamma=255-gamma;
}
```